# Better approach to scrape with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I started palying with JSoup today.So as an example I started with scraping proxies from this [site](http://www.samair.ru/proxy/socks01.htm).

After playing a lot , I was able to scrape the proxies, but without their port numbers as they were using JavaScript. I wanted to know can we scrape those port numbers also with JSoup. As this was my first attempt, I wanted to know if the approach I took was right. So I am posting the code that could fetch proxies.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;

public class ListLinks
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/socks01.htm").get();
            Elements content = doc.select("table.tablelist tbody tr ");
            for(Element com: content)
            {
                Element fi=com.select("td").first();
                String e=fi.text();
                String safe=Jsoup.clean(e,Whitelist.basic());
                System.out.println(safe);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          System.out.print("Problem");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This should go to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is ok.

But one thing: There's no need for `String safe=Jsoup.clean(e,Whitelist.basic());`
since `String e=fi.text();` will give you a clean string.

Comment: Thanks, but can i also scrape port no from that url,i think that uses javascript.Also can i use jsoup to scrape from websites that uses Ajax and javascript?For eg. can i scrape proxies from sites from this page: [link](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/)

Comment: Unfortunately javascript is not supportet by Jsoup. But you can try [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) for JavaScript execution. [Here](http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/)'s a good example.

Comment: Ok Thanks i will have a look at ScriptEngine.